# Personal access token only to modify repositories GITHUB

Tags: git, api, github, oauth

I want to select the correct option that will allow this API key to modify my repositories by only **pushing** to them (adding content).
Which one of the following options do I select here? I want to limit the key as much as possible.

It will also only be pushing to **public** repos that I have.

I think its under **repo**, maybe repo deployment ... but hat makes me feel like its the ability to **create** repos. I want to basically only **modify ** one.
 [image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That would be the [`public-repo` scope](https://developer.github.com/apps/building-oauth-apps/understanding-scopes-for-oauth-apps/#available-scopes), which is narrower than the repo scope according to [this issue](https://github.com/prose/prose/issues/816).

However, the "write" access does not distinguish between push and new repo, as illustrated in [GitHub Repo "Create" API](https://developer.github.com/v3/repos/#create)

> When using OAuth, authorizations must include:
>
> - public_repo scope or repo scope to create a public repository
> - repo scope to create a private repository

I am not aware of a narrower scope though.